# PHP include files pushed to Website

Tags: php, import

When you're creating a new website, and you add your PHP files, do the PHP imports your code uses also get pushed up?

Or is there an option to upload them as well?

Comment: you kind of need to give more details before your question makes sense. Just "php files" don't do anything. Who are you creating a website with? Did you check their tutorials?

Comment: I meant in general. Let's say I have an index.html which contains a form. The user submits a URL using the form and the .php script processes that submission and opens a new webpage with the specified URL (making use of some external HTTP Requests API). Do these extra API need to be packaged together with the .php code when you're actually uploading your HTML & php files?

Comment: there is no "in general". Your comment has nothing to do with your question, which is about uploading your PHP files somewhere, not about your website users doing something. This is about your project, hosted with some domain hoster, who may or may not have a simple, or elaborate, PHP install already available for you. Without additional information, no one can answer this question except you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are responsible for uploading any PHP file (or any file for that mater) that you have updated even if they reference each other.  The `include()` command is only processed when the PHP page is accessed from a running web server.

Answer (score 0):

Remote file may be processed at the remote server (depending on the file extension and the fact if the remote server runs PHP or not) but it still has to produce a valid PHP script because it will be processed at the local server. If the file from the remote server should be processed there and outputted only, readfile() is much better function to use. Otherwise, special care should be taken to secure the remote script to produce a valid and desired code.

More info in:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php